# Why does this JavaScript snippet return true?

Tags: javascript

Saw this example as a mental exercise. I don't understand why it returns true. Surely the inner `this` should be scoped to the anonymous function and the outer `this` is not related to that function at all.

```js
var result = (function() {
  return this;
}()) === this;

var el = document.createElement("div")
el.innerHTML = result;
document.body.appendChild(el)
```

Comment: `console.log(this);`

Comment: `this` is not related to scope, it depends on how you call the function.

Comment: the "this" your function is referring to the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not much scoping here, only "context".

As the IIFE is invoked without a context then the inner `this` defaults to `window` (except in ES5 "strict mode") that also being the default value of `this` in the global scope.

Comment: Oh dear. Why doesn't 'use strict' cause an error to be thrown instead of changing the value of the result?

Comment: because it's perfectly possible (via `call` or `apply`) to supply a context to that function.  An incorrect `this` is (in my experience) always a programmer error, not a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not about scoping, but context.

Context (i.e. this) in JS is normally set to be the object against which the function is invoked.

In this case  no user defined object invokes the IIFE, so the context inside it defaults to the global object, hence true.

Specifying strict mode will cause the context inside the IIFE to be undefined reducing the likelihood of accidental global object changes.